# There is a problem when processing the PDF file created with Kendo UI PDF into the Java pdfbox library

Tags: java, pdf, kendo-ui, pdfbox

First, I am sorry that my English is not good.

I created a PDF file with Kendo UI PDF. 
This generated file was processed using a Java pdfbox library.
Processed content is text addition and image addition.
But the results were not good.

The added text and images are displayed upside down.

[Text is reverse in generated pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924286/text-is-reverse-in-generated-pdf)

Like the letters displayed on this link, all my results are displayed upside down

Testing with a different PDF file did not cause any problems.
However, the PDF created with Kendo UI PDF is problematic.

In addition, PDF files created with Kendo UI PDF also result in the following error in areas where the coordinates of text are obtained by overriding the writeString method of the pdfbox PrintTextLocator.

java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of TTF stream connected

Similar to the preceding issues, there is no problem with using other PDF files. However, the PDF created with Kendo UI PDF is problematic.

I think only PDF files created with Kendo UI PDF have this problem.

As far as possible, I hope the PDF produced by Kendo UI PDF works well.

I want to find out what the solution.
Thank you.

No problem occurred when text and images were added to a file other than the PDF file created by Kendo UI PDF.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout

A PDF file was created by the method provided by this link.
I added text and images using a Java pdfbox library as a file created here.

```
    function getPDF(selector) {
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(selector)).then(function (group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Invoice.pdf");
        });
    }
```

Below is where you add text and images using the pdfbox library.

Code to add text :

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(file1));
    PDPage page = document.getPage(page);

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
    contentStream.showText(text);
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();

    document.save(new File(file2));
    document.close();
```

Code to add image :

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(file1));

    BufferedImage tmpImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imgFile));
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(tmpImage.getWidth(),

    tmpImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawRenderedImage(tmpImage, null);

    PDImageXObject image = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);
    PDPage page = document.getPage(page);

    try(PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true)) {
        contentStream.drawImage(image, x, y);
    }

    document.save(new File(file2));
    document.close();
```

Comment: I'm using pdfbox 2.0.16 version.

Comment: But your code has the same mistake as the answer you are linking to?! (5th parameter of the PDPageContentStream constructor is missing and should be true)

Comment: PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);

If you set the fifth generator value to true, it will not be displayed upside down but will be displayed correctly.
However, the y-axis position of the text and image appears to be randomly changed if there are five generators.

Comment: PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

When you have four constructors, the text and images are correctly located.
However, text and images are displayed upside down.

Comment: The x and y values are the same, but the results depend on the constructor.

If we had 5 generators, why would they have the same coordinates, but they're different?

Comment: Then please share a source file that brings the effect (upload to a sharehoster and link to it). What do you mean with "randomly changed", does it change everytime for the same file? Also check the cropbox of the page. (PDPage.getCropBox()). Maybe the y in the cropbox doesn't start at 0. (y=0 is the bottom)